# How can I simulate svnversion command in git?

Tags: git, svn

From `svnversion` documentation:

> ```
> [adrdec@opsynxvm0081 common_cpp]$ svnversion --help
> usage: svnversion [OPTIONS] [WC_PATH [TRAIL_URL]]
> ```
>
> Produce a compact 'version number' for the working copy path
>   WC_PATH.    For example:
>
> ```
> $ svnversion . /repos/svn/trunk
> 4168
> ```
>
> The version number will be a single number if the working   copy is
>   single revision, unmodified, not switched and with   an URL that
>   matches the TRAIL_URL argument.  If the working   copy is unusual the
>   version number will be more complex:
>
> ```
>    4123:4168     mixed revision working copy
>    4168M         modified working copy
>    4123S         switched working copy
>    4123P         partial working copy, from a sparse checkout
>    4123:4168MS   mixed revision, modified, switched working copy
> ```

Comment: And people say SVN is simple .. :(

Comment: There's no direct equivalent in Git, since Git has different concepts of "modified" (ie staged and unstaged), refers to its commits differently, doesn't have a concept of "switching", etc etc. To be able to give you something useful, can you explain what you want the command for?

Comment: I need to store information in the binaries about the version and status of the code used in the compilation process.

Comment: If you are storing the version number in the binaries, then all but a simple number from `svnversion` are useless. As all others are impossible to reproduce from just the repository and version number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution detects changes in the working directory like svnversion does.

```
    def get_version(self, path):
            curdir = self.get_cur_dir()
            os.chdir(path)
            version = self.execute_command("git log --pretty=format:%H -n1")[self.OUT].strip()  #get the last revision and it's comment
            status = self.execute_command("git status")[self.OUT].strip()  #get the status of the working copy
            if "modified" in status or "added" in status or "deleted" in status:
                    version += self.modified
            os.chdir(curdir)
            return version


    def execute_command(self, cmd_list):
            proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
            (out, err) = proc.communicate()
            rc = proc.returncode
            return rc, out, err
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not super familar with SVN, but from what I can tell, SVN identifies revisions in the form of simple numbers: 1, 2, 3... Git doesn't translate so well, since it uses SSH hashes to identify revisions (known as 'commits' in the Git world). However, getting this is still pretty simple using `git log`:

```
git log --pretty="format:%h" -n1 HEAD
```

This prints the currently checked-out commit in the repo (which is what HEAD is). Alternatively, you can replace `HEAD` in the command with `master` (or any other branch, for that matter) to get the last commit of that branch, rather than the one that represents your working directory. Additionally, if you need the full SHA1, replace `%h` above with `%H`. You can also read the `git-log` manpage for more about `--pretty` formats.

Additionally, you could add an alias in `.gitconfig` to do this anywhere. Add the following lines to `~/.gitconfig` (leave off `[alias]` if your `.gitconfig` already has that section, however):

```
[alias]
    rev = "git log --pretty='format:%h'"
```

Now, any time you're in a Git repo and you want to see the current revision, just type `git rev`.

Comment: Thanks, but I am after the revision, in Git it's not very useful to get the revision count. Taking your script I'd rather do:  git log --pretty=oneline|head -n 1 | sed 's/\s.*//'

Comment: Does that work? There's a bit cleaner way of just getting the current commit/revision using `git log --pretty="format:%h" -n1 HEAD`. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: yes it does. Nevertheless your solution is better, although I would use: git log --pretty="format:%H" -n1   Since you want the current full hash.